# cannot create a ipa for ios testflight

Tags: ios, testflight

Hello I have followed the steps in the links

http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/402741-how-to-create-an-ipa-xcode-3-

At step 4, when i try got the pop up, i do not see the testflight icon. I have not download their sdk or anything. Just created an account. And when i save it to my disk. I got an somename.app folder. What i should do now? Please help

Thanks
Samin

Comment: Those instructions are for Xcode 3. You're not using Xcode 4?

Comment: no i checked. i am using 3.2.5.. do i need to use xcode 4 ?

Comment: Apple no longer support Xcode 3. The latest iOS SDK is only available with Xcode 4, which also requires Mac OS X Lion (10.7).

Comment: i am using xcode 3.2.5 with ios 4.2 in snow leopard.. they had a tutorial for xcode 3. so i believe there is a way

Comment: That is an old tutorial. You'll notice that the dates in the screenshots show 2010 - 2 years ago.

Comment: yeah i upgraded it to xcode 4 and it worked.. thanks buddy

Comment: @Jasarien: thanks i updated to xcode 4 and it works..:)

Comment: @Jasarien: will you post it as a answer ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instructions are written for Xcode 3, which is no longer supported by Apple.

You should upgrade to Xcode 4.